# Disable Desktop Icon Auto-Arrange on Login/Startup in Windows 10, VGA and Displayport to VGA monitors connected

Tags: windows-10, desktop, displayport

I'm trying to troubleshoot a way to keep my desktop from auto-reverting upon login/startup. I'm running an HP laptop into a docking station with a single VGA cable and a Displayport to VGA for my monitors. It seems that the Displayport to VGA is registering after login/startup and any icon arrangement(Using solely the primary monitor) still reverts to default arrangement after sign in. Any way to work around this? I know I probably won't be able to organize anything on my secondary(DisplayPort) monitor, but being able to keep things together on the main monitor is preferable.

Comment: See this page>>>>>>>https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/57518-turn-off-auto-arrange-desktop-icons-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your problem is not the
[Auto Arrange of Desktop Icons](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/57518-turn-off-auto-arrange-desktop-icons-windows-10-a.html),
but rather changes in screen resolution. Such changes cause Windows to pack all
the icons on one side of the screen.

This is a very old "feature" of Windows. I suppose that the logic of the
Microsoft developers who first came up with this idea was to ensure that all
the icons fit into the screen under the new resolution. This initial software
was never redone or improved since decades.

This problem is one that is a great annoyance, with which I have unfortunately much
experience. I never found a solution for it using Windows tools, so I had to try
third-party ones.

Of the many such free tools that I tried, I have kept two donationware products:

- [Iconoid by SillySot Software](https://www.sillysot.com/)
- [ReIcon by Sordum](https://www.sordum.org/)

Both tools have the ability to remember the position of desktop icons,
either by the current resolution or by absolute positions,
and can return them to their place with a couple of clicks.

I use these tools every time that Windows moves my icons, to return them to their
right places.

Comment: Thank you for the software recommendation, part of my frustration comes from the inconsistency I see with the fact that my colleagues don't experience the same iconic issues that I am having. I've verified that the auto-sort is off, I'm hoping to find a configuration solution over managing another program if possible

Comment: Whether the problem happens or not depends on the nature of the resolution change.